# How to convert DateTime datatype of java in to DATE in mysql

Tags: mysql

**I have a date like:-**

> Thu Dec 26 05:24:05 UTC 2013

and I want to convert this date like this

> 26th Dec 2013

I want solution for it.

Comment: Can you provide more details? You speak of Java, so this should not be a problem as you could use JDBC which can do the conversion. So, please add to your question: where is the source date format stored and where do you want to store the target format? What do you want to use? mysql command line? java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date you have is a string and in `mysql` you need to use [`str_to_date()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) in conjunction with [`date_format()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to get the date in a formatted pattern

```
mysql> select 
        date_format( 
            str_to_date(
               'Thu Dec 26 05:24:05 UTC 2013','%a %b %d %h:%i:%s UTC %Y'
             ),'%D %b %Y'
         ) as date;
+---------------+
| date          |
+---------------+
| 26th Dec 2013 |
+---------------+
```

Comment: It's not working still.                                          SELECT date_format(str_to_date('Fri Jan 31 22:06:30 UTC 2014','%a %b %d %h:%i:%s UTC %Y'),'%D %b %Y');

Answer (score 0):

From a date object, you can individually extract date.

```
Date dte=new Date();

dte.format(dd.MM..YYYY);
```

for more information, visit http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm